# Python: Calculate week start and week end from daily data in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a daily dataset for different months.
I want to calculate the week start(sunday) and week end(saturday) based on each product type & country and values should be the average for that particular week.

```
dates                   product        country      value  name

2021-10-01 00:00:00     Voice           Lucia       2      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     TV              Jamai       1      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     TV              Trin        5      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     Voice           Gren        5      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     Broad           Vin         7      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     TV              Gren        8      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     Broad           Barb        5      A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     Voice           Jamai       23     A
2021-10-01 00:00:00     Voice           Trin        6      A  
2021-10-01 00:00:00     TV              Cur         7      A
2021-10-02 00:00:00     Broad           Jamai       2      A
2021-10-03 00:00:00     Broad           Trin        8      A
2021-10-04 00:00:00     Broad           Lucia       3      A
2021-10-04 00:00:00     TV              Anti        1      A
2021-10-04 00:00:00     Broad           Cur         8      A
2021-10-04 00:00:00     Voice           Barb        0      A
2021-10-04 00:00:00     TV              Vin         5      A
2021-10-04 00:00:00     Voice           Vin         1      A
2021-10-05 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN
2021-10-06 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN
2021-10-07 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN  
2021-10-08 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN      
2021-10-09 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN  
2021-10-10 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN  
2021-10-11 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN  
2021-10-12 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN      
2021-10-13 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN      
2021-10-14 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN      
2021-10-15 00:00:00     NAN             NAN         NAN    NAN      
...............
..............................etc
```

**SAMPLE result format:**

```
week_start   week_end   product   country   name value(**average of values for each week**)
```

I tried with groupby but I'm not able to get week start and end for each product and country.

Also Values should be the average(addition) for that particular week.
Any help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to create a new column for the start date and end date for the date of each row. This can be done by using offsets.Week:

```
import pandas as pd    

df['start'] = df['dates'] - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6)
df['end'] = df['start'] + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=5)
```

From there you can use groupby to group by the start, end, product and country columns and use the mean aggregation method for the value column:

```
df.groupby(['start','end','product','country']).agg({'value': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to use offsets.week. Can you pls help.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.Week'

Comment: Judging by the 'str' in the error message, your dates are in string format, not datetime. To change them to datetime use to_datetime like df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])